# input data to another table if the (source cell) row is blank

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way where we can create another sheet(Sheet B) for it to be automatically added if an order ID, (Column B) is blank and removed if its already filled in Column B (Sheet A)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is... try this formula in any cell of `Sheet2`:

```
 =query(Sheet1!A5:B,"select A where B is null")
```

**EDIT**

If, on the other hand, you want Order Numbers to remain in place, without scaling up, then use this formula:

```
=index(if(Sheet1!B5:B<>"",,Sheet1!A5:A))
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Is it possible to have this formula to stop the value from shifting up when removed? We use Array, Transpose to divide the order numbers equally.

Comment: Yes, check out the update to my post

Comment: Awesome! Both formulas work flawlessly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello again! Is it possible to use the index formula on multiple columns? For the table above, what if we want to add Column C? (If column B and C have data on Sheet 1 - remove them, and if 1 is missing in either column, it will appear.)